# Python get multiple docx file names and extract specific words from the files to generate a dataframe or table

Tags: python, text-mining, python-docx, docx2txt

I hope to read multiple word documents (docx files) in a folder and then search a specific word e.g. "laptop" from each of docx file to generate a table or a dataframe.
For instance: in my folder I have file_1.docx, file_2.docx ... file_n.docx, each file may or may not contain work "Laptop". In the end I hope to generate a table like:

```
FileName          Keyword
file_1.docx       "laptop"
file_2.docx       "laptop"
...
```

Comment: There are plenty of libraries out there that can help solve this problem - pick a set of tools and get started on some code. If you run into specific problems writing code, share the code here and ask about the problems and someone will be able to help. StackOverflow is not the right place to ask for recommendations on what libraries to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Python3.X you will need to do

> pip install python-docx

Not to be confuse with docx as I had some issues using this.

```
import os
from docx import Document
import pandas as pd

match_word = "laptop"
match_items = []
folder = 'C:\\Dev\\Docs'
file_names = os.listdir(folder)
file_names = [file for file in file_names if file.endswith('.docx')]
file_names = [os.path.join(folder, file) for file in file_names]

For file in file_names:
    document = Document(file)
    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        if match_word in paragraph.text:
            match_items.append([file, match_word])

the_df = pd.DataFrame(
    match_items,
    columns=['file_name', 'word_match'],
    index=[i[0] for i in match_items]
)

print(the_df)
```

Output:

```
file_name              word_match
C:\Dev\Docs\c.docx     laptop
```

Comment: This method will work *most* of the time, but words can span multiple text runs ( e.g. the word multiple could be broken into `mul`, `tip`, and `le` if the user made a typo and later came back to correct it.)  This is accounted for with the `merge-consecutive-text` setting of simplify-docx which is built on top of the python-docx package...